# TiBCO Spotfire - How to Calculate only the last 3 columns in a Data - see descr

Tags: tibco, spotfire, calculation

```
Week    Sales
1   100
2   250
3   350
4   145
5   987
6   26
7   32
8   156
```

I wanted to calculate the sales only for the last 3 weeks so the total will be 156+32+26.

If new weeks are added it should automatically calculate only the data from the last 3 rows.

Tried this formula but it is returning an incorrect sum

`sum(sales) over (lastperiod(3(week))`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y7h7.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the last 3 weeks sum in calculated column you can use a simple if calculation.

```
If([week]>(Max([week]) - 3),Sum([sales]),0)
```

If you need 3 weeks calculation throughout table use below one.

```
sum([sales]) OVER (LastPeriods(3,[week]))
```

[image: Results]

Comment: I tried the first formula and i got the answer as below

Comment: I tried the first formula and i got the answer as for week 6 198 for week 7 198 for week 8 198, when i used the second formula it's giving me as 5649. The actual answer should be 26+32+156

Comment: see picture in my first comment i am getting 214 (26+32+156)

Comment: Also I was looking to calculate the standard deviation for last 3 weeks. Every time a new week is added it should automatically calculate the standard deviation for last 3 weeks. Could you please help me on this one?

Comment: @Sanju If Julie's answer fixed your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark button next to it. And if you've got a followup question regarding standard, please ask a new question instead of commenting on your old one.

Comment: i didnt get the context. anyway if its for only last 3 weeks you can try same calculation.  If([week]>(Max([week]) - 3),StdDev([sales]),0)

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Sanju consider accepting this answer if it is correct for the rest of the community